# How to call a function when the App is resumed after been closed or minimized in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I need to check network things of my Application when the app is resumed after been closed or minimized (It's means when the app starts or is resumed after been minimized) and I don't know how to do it. I just want to call a function when this happens. No matter what view would be. Undependent of the view, I need to call that function (It a simple fetch to check the session).
I hope you understand my poor english, thanks for all.
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your app's state by using AppState API. react-native already support this feature.

FYI: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html